# Writing celery3.13 logs to syslog using Python

Tags: logging, celery, syslog

Hi can some one help me with a sample code that helps me to write celery3.13 logs to syslog using Python.

Answer (score 2):

I know this was an old post -- but I stumbled across it while researching the same problem.  I thought I'd share the approach we selected.
Put this code in `app/__init__.py`

```
import logging
from celery.signals import after_setup_logger, after_setup_task_logger

def setup_handler(sender=None, logger=None, loglevel=None,
       logfile=None, fmt=None, colorize=None, **kwds):
    r"""create a syslog handler"""
    handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address='/dev/log')
    handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(fmt))
    handler.setLevel(loglevel or logging.INFO)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

after_setup_logger.connect(setup_handler)
after_setup_task_logger.connect(setup_handler)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that on celery 4 fmt has been renamed to format.

```
import logging
from celery.signals import after_setup_logger, after_setup_task_logger

def setup_handler(sender=None, logger=None, loglevel=None,
   logfile=None, format=None, colorize=None, **kwds):
  r"""create a syslog handler"""
  handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address='/dev/log')
  handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(format))
  handler.setLevel(loglevel or logging.INFO)
  logger.addHandler(handler)

after_setup_logger.connect(setup_handler)
after_setup_task_logger.connect(setup_handler)
```